# Search column for matching data

Tags: sql, html-table

I have a table with a few columns.  I want to get data from two of the columns; email and URL.

One column being email.  I want distinct emails.

The second column is a url.  I want to get only the urls that match what I'm looking for, for example, xyz.

So the table looks like this:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>URL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>user@yahoo.com</td>
<td>xyz</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>user@gmail.com</td>
<td>abc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>user@outlook.com</td>
<td>xyz</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>user@email.com</td>
<td>xyz</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How do I execute a query so that only the emails from the xyz url are found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I’m missing something, you just need to do:

```
Select  Distinct Email
From    YourTable
Where   URL = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Arrrr...i was missing the single quote '

Comment: Apparently single quotes come out as smart quotes when posting on mobile.  I can’t figure out how to fix it, if someone would like to edit it.

Comment: Done.  Thanks again.